# Need help making a counting program

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

So my professor told me to make a General purpose counting program for him using C# **(Console Application)**

This is the program specification:
Design, write and test a program to
display any list of numbers, given the starting
number (lower limit), the final number (upper
limit) and the step size. Eg. 0,2,4,6,8 (LowerLimit = 0, Upperlimit = 8, StepSize = 2)

I wrote pseudo code for it:

1. Set up variables to store the 3 numbers and the
   loop counter
2. Store the lower limit entered by the user
3. Store the upper limit entered by the user
4. Store the step size entered by the user
5. Repeat the following, starting at lower limit, and
   going up to upper limit in steps of stepsize
6. Display the counter
7. End of loop

I am struggling to translate step 5 into C# code.

This is what I have done so far:-

```
class Program
{
    public static Single lowerLimit, upperLimit, stepSizes, counter, upperScaler;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the lower limit ");
        lowerLimit = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the upper limit ");
        upperLimit = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the step sizes ");
        stepSizes = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();

        for (counter = lowerLimit; counter <= upperScaler; counter++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counter * stepSizes);
            if (counter != 1)
            {
                upperScaler = upperLimit / stepSizes;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read a tutorial about For loops.

Comment: I think while loop would be better to use since you need to increment counter=counter+stepsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

- Repeat the following, starting at lower limit, and going up to upper limit in steps of stepsize
- Display the counter

starting at lower limit : int count = lowerLimit
going up to upper limit : count <= upperLimit
in steps of stepsize : count+=stepSizes
Display the counter : Console.WriteLine(count)

```
for (int count = lowerLimit; count <= upperLimit; count+=stepSizes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

Do validate the user inputs.

**Update**

To address, op's query in comment

if upperLimit == lowerLimit OR stepSizes == 0, skip loop
if upperLimit > lowerLimit , check stepSizes > 0
if upperLimit < lowerLimit , check stepSizes < 0

Comment: Thanks but: just say if the user inputed:- Lower: 10 , Upper: 0 , stepsize: -2 , this wouldn't work then right?

Comment: @EesaKhan yes, that won't work. Thats why I have asked to validate user inputs in last line. Check for lowerLimit & upperLimit values, and stepsize != 0;

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
for (counter = lowerLimit; counter <= upperScaler; counter += stepSizes) {}
```

but you should guard yourself from going infinite with stepSizes of 0

Answer (score 0):

> Repeat the following, starting at lower limit, and going up to upper limit in steps of stepsize

You obviously need a loop similar to this one:

```
for (int counter = lowerLimit; counter <= upperLimit; counter = counter + stepSizes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all well, but... what's upperScaler?
And what if your counter is incremented directly by the stepSize quantity?

Better (and simpler) to do this way:

```
for (counter = lowerLimit; counter <= upperLimit; counter+=stepSizes)
{
   Console.WriteLine(counter);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is what your professor wants you to do;